# Не выводятся параметры в components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

Есть компонент Navbar. С бэка я получаю названия вкладок, по которым пользоватeль может перейти, но они не отображаются. Почему? Как решить проблему?

components/Navbar.vue

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link"  id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Студентам
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu size-navbar-text" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <template v-for="article in students">
                <div :key="article.id">
                  <nuxt-link class="dropdown-item"  :to="`/students/${article.id}`">{{article.title}}</nuxt-link>
                </div> 
              </template>
            </div>
          </li>
```

Забираю данные с бэка:

```
<script>
export default {
  async asyncData({ $axios, params }) {
    try {
      let students = await $axios.$get(`/students/`);
      return { students }
    } catch (e) {
      return { students: []};
    }
  },
  data({ params }) {
    return {
      students: {
      },
    };
  },

}
</script>
```

Comment: А в каком месте Вы вызывает код, который получает данные?

Comment: В компоненте Navbar.

Comment: Я понял. Но где строка вызова?